# How to define a default column value in Rails for a text column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

1.MySQL do not support default values for text columns (so i cannot use migration to specify the default value)

2.The following code

```
after_initialize do |obj|
  obj.column1 ||= "default_value"
end
```

is buggy. E.g. it will override explicitly specified values for the following cases: `MyModel.new(column1: nil)` or `MyModel.new { |obj| obj.column1 = nil }`

So the only simple and more or less correct approach is I can think of is:

```
after_initialize do |obj|
  obj.column1 ="default_value" if obj.new_record? and !obj.column1_changed?
end
```

Could you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Why not using before_validation callback?

```
before_validation(on: :create) do
  self.column1 != "default value"
end
```

update

you can still avoid `new_record?` :)

```
before_validation(on: :create) do
  self.column1 = "default value" unless self.column1_changed?
end
```

Comment: It's also buggy solution. Consider cases: MyModel.new(column1: nil) and MyModel.new { |obj| obj.column1 = nil }

Comment: Ahh sorry. Now i do undestand what you mean. Normally i don't want user to set a nil value when i want a default value to be set. I think there is no way to check if column is explicitly specified nil other then using `_changed?` method.